Connection problems with APISIX in GCP Cloud Run
I would like to set up APISIX in the Google Cloud Platform on a Cloud Run instance and configure other Cloud Run instances as upstreams.
My APISIX setup:
I configure my APISIX Cloud Run container with the following files:
# Dockerfile

FROM apache/apisix

COPY ./configs/config.yaml /usr/local/apisix/conf/config.yaml
COPY ./configs/apisix.yaml /usr/local/apisix/conf/apisix.yaml

configs/apisix.yaml

routes:
  - 
    uri: /hello
    plugins:
      proxy-rewrite:
        uri: /hello
    upstream:
      nodes:
        "<CLOUD_RUN_URL>.run.app": 1
      scheme: https
#END

configs/config.yaml

deployment:
  role: data_plane
  role_data_plane:
    config_provider: yaml
#END

I build and push the Docker Image to GCPs Artifact Registry and then I build both Cloud Run Services using the following Terraform Code:
# main.tf

# APISIX Docker Image
data "google_artifact_registry_docker_image" "apisix_image" {
  project       = var.project_id
  location      = "europe-west3"
  repository_id = <ARTIFACT_REGISTRY>
  image_name    = "<APISIX_IMAGE>:latest"
}

# Cloud Run APISIX
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "apisix" {
  project  = var.project_id
  location = "europe-west3"
  name     = "apisix"
  ingress  = "INGRESS_TRAFFIC_INTERNAL_LOAD_BALANCER"

  template {
    containers {
      image = data.google_artifact_registry_docker_image.apisix_image.self_link
      ports {
        container_port = 9080
      }
      env {
        name  = "APISIX_STAND_ALONE"
        value = true
      }
    }
    vpc_access {
      egress = "ALL_TRAFFIC"
      network_interfaces {
        network    = "<NETWORK_NAME>"
        subnetwork = "<SUBNETWORK_NAME>"
      }
    }
  }
}

# Cloud Run Upstream API
resource "google_cloud_run_v2_service" "api" {
  project  = var.project_id
  location = "europe-west3"
  name     = "upstream-api"
  ingress  = "INGRESS_TRAFFIC_INTERNAL_LOAD_BALANCER"

  template {
    containers {
      image = "us-docker.pkg.dev/cloudrun/container/hello"
    }
  }
}


However, if I deploy the whole thing in GCP I get a 404 error and the request never reaches my upstream cloud run container. Both Cloud Run services are in the same GCP project.
Error Log:: When I try to access the Cloud Run Upstream URL, I get the following error log in the APISIX Cloud Run Service:
<APISIX_Cloud_Run_URL> "GET /hello HTTP/1.1" 404 36 0.050 "-" "curl" 199.36.153.9:443 404 0.019 "<APISIX_Cloud_Run_URL>/hello"
It can be seen that APISIX can correctly determine the IP of the upstream to be called ...
It is also interesting that I can reach the upstream cloud run container from another cloud run container running a FastAPI service (with the Python requests package). This FastAPI Cloud Run Service is configured in exactly the same way as the APISIX Cloud Run Service. So the whole thing sounds to me very much like a problem with APISIX itself.
Do any of you have experience with this or a similar setup? If you need more details, I am happy to provide more information.
Thanks in advance for any advice and help!
Additional info: I also found out the following - If I put an internal load balancer in front of the upstream cloud run service and configure the internal IP of the load balancer (alternatively also a private DNS domain) as an upstream node in APISIX, I can reach the backend. This means that, in principle, internal IPs/URLs can be resolved/reached by APISIX. However, for some reason it does not work with the Cloud Run URL.

Unless my knowledge is outdated, Cloud Run doesn't accept Docker Compose (docker-compose.yml) files as deployment configuration, so please update your question with specific details (i.e. commands and response) of how you're deploying these service to Cloud Run and how you're then interacting with them.

You're absolutely right, thanks for pointing that out. I got my local setup and the cloud deployment mixed up when I posted the question. For Cloud Run I use a Dockerfile and the config files - I included the Dockerfile in the post.

I also added an additional info and the http error log from the APISIX Cloud Run

Your question is not a minimal repro making it difficult for others to help. You make statements but don't provide evidence: How do you create the local setup? What did you then do to demonstrate it worked? How did you deploy to Cloud Run?

Thanks again for your answer,
I think the Local Setup actually does not help in solving or discussing the actual problem. I have therefore removed the content from the post.
Basically, the question remains for me why APISIX cannot reach the URL of a cloud run service in the same project.  I use Terraform to deploy the two Cloud Run Services (APISIX and Upstream API). I have attached the code to the post.

Look up what this endpoint means in Cloud Run /health. In networking and services designs do you understand what 404 means? Before posting a problem like yours, perform normal debugging to identify what the problem is and where the problem is. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/healthchecks

I don't understand what you mean. The problem has nothing to do with the Cloud Run health checks. The only question is why the internally deployed API cannot be reached by the APISIX container, which is also internal ...
The log entry with the health refers to the health endpoint of the api, which I cannot reach.

I have been debugging this problem for several days and simply cannot explain why the containers cannot reach each other. From another container (just as deployed as APISIX) I can reach the API with normal Python requests ... only the APISIX service causes problems

I made a mistake reading your post. I saw /hello as /health. Ignore my previous comment.

In Cloud Run, the 404 error can be returned by either the Cloud Run GFE (proxy) or your containerized application. An important item is to figure out which one is returning the 404 error.

Here’s my thoughts regarding your issue with APISIX service. APISIX might not handle certain host headers or HTTPS-based upstreams correctly out of the box. This could result in misrouting or failure to resolve upstreams.
Add a proxy-rewrite plugin configuration in your apisix.yaml to explicitly set the Host header to match the upstream's Cloud Run URL.
routes:
  -
    uri: /hello
    plugins:
      proxy-rewrite:
        uri: /get
        headers:
          Host: "<CLOUD_RUN_URL>.run.app"
    upstream:
      nodes:
        "<CLOUD_RUN_URL>.run.app": 1
      scheme: https

Hope this one works!

Thank you for your answer! That was the trick. I just had to change
"headers:
Host: "
to
"host: "
